# How can I make VSCode keybindings override keybindings for the terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here's an example:

- In most terminals (including VSCode's) `Control + M` sends the `Return` key (carriage return) to the shell.
- I would like **instead** for it to follow my defined keybinding in `keybindings.json`. In my case for example, `Control + M` would be used to build **chords** with other commands (e.g. `Ctrl+M` `Ctrl+S` to hide/show the side bar, whether I trigger it from the Panel in the terminal or anywhere else).

Is there a way to override terminal keybindings with VSCode ones?

Comment: Oh nice. Thanks @Mark - I didn't know about it. Let me read more (and by the feel free to add it as an answer)

Comment: Thanks @mark - Maybe I'm missing something but reading through [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_forcing-key-bindings-to-pass-through-the-terminal), it's not clear to me how I can specifically exempt `Control+M` which is a keybinding and not a VSCode commandID per se.